# unequal vector in xml from different nodes

Tags: r, xml2

I am trying to extract data from https://prtr.defra.gov.uk/full-dataset and the file is called uk_prtr_dataset_2021.xml

```
library(xml2)
library(dplyr) 

xml_file <- read_xml('uk_prtr_dataset_2021.xml')
```

I want to extract following nodes

```
node_vec <- c("ParentCompanyName", "FacilityName", "LongitudeMeasure", "LatitudeMeasure", "MainEconomicActivityName")

for(node in seq_along(node_vec)){

  node_ref <- node_vec[node]
  var_ref <- paste0(".//rsm:",node_ref)

  temp <- xml_file %>%   
           xml_find_all(var_ref) %>%
           as_list() %>%
           simplify() %>%
           enframe() %>%
           unnest(value) %>%
           unnest(value)

print(paste0(node_ref,": ",nrow(temp)))
}

[1] "ParentCompanyName: 6305"
[1] "FacilityName: 6306"
[1] "LongitudeMeasure: 6305"
[1] "LatitudeMeasure: 6305"
[1] "MainEconomicActivityName: 6305"
```

However, I see that `FacilityName` has one extra entry due to which I cannot bind the 5 columns together. Is there anyway I can figure out which is the extra entry so that I can remove it.

EDIT: A small part of XML

<rsm:PollutantReleaseAndTransferReport xmlns:rsm="urn:eu:com:env:prtr:data:standard:2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:eu:com:env:prtr:data:standard:2 [http://www.eionet.europa.eu/schemas/eprtr/PollutantReleaseAndTransferReport_2p0.xsd">](http://www.eionet.europa.eu/schemas/eprtr/PollutantReleaseAndTransferReport_2p0.xsd%22%3E)rsm:ReportingYear2021</rsm:ReportingYear>rsm:CountryIDUK</rsm:CountryID>rsm:CoordinateSystemIDEPSG:4326</rsm:CoordinateSystemID>rsm:RemarkTextNone</rsm:RemarkText>rsm:CompetentAuthorityPartyrsm:NameBEIS</rsm:Name>rsm:Addressrsm:StreetName1 Victoria Street</rsm:StreetName>rsm:CityNameLondon</rsm:CityName>rsm:PostcodeCodeSW1H 0ET</rsm:PostcodeCode></rsm:Address>rsm:TelephoneCommunicationrsm:CompleteNumberText00 44 774 169 9372</rsm:CompleteNumberText></rsm:TelephoneCommunication>rsm:FaxCommunicationrsm:CompleteNumberText--</rsm:CompleteNumberText></rsm:FaxCommunication>rsm:EmailCommunicationrsm:EmailURIIDShamim.Choudhury@beis.gov.uk</rsm:EmailURIID></rsm:EmailCommunication>rsm:ContactPersonNameShamim Choudhury</rsm:ContactPersonName></rsm:CompetentAuthorityParty>rsm:CompetentAuthorityPartyrsm:NameE1</rsm:Name>rsm:Addressrsm:StreetNameAll correspondence to: Defra, Industrial Pollution, 5F Ergon House, Horseferry Rd. London.</rsm:StreetName>rsm:CityNameLondon</rsm:CityName>rsm:PostcodeCodeSW1P 2AL</rsm:PostcodeCode></rsm:Address>rsm:TelephoneCommunicationrsm:CompleteNumberTextChange Me</rsm:CompleteNumberText></rsm:TelephoneCommunication>rsm:FaxCommunicationrsm:CompleteNumberTextChange Me</rsm:CompleteNumberText></rsm:FaxCommunication>rsm:EmailCommunicationrsm:EmailURIIDprtr@defra.gsi.gov.uk</rsm:EmailURIID></rsm:EmailCommunication>rsm:ContactPersonNameNational Data Manager</rsm:ContactPersonName></rsm:CompetentAuthorityParty>rsm:CompetentAuthorityPartyrsm:NameE10</rsm:Name>rsm:Addressrsm:StreetNameAll correspondence to: Defra, Industrial Pollution, 5F Ergon House, Horseferry Rd. London.</rsm:StreetName>rsm:CityNameLondon</rsm:CityName>rsm:PostcodeCodeSW1P 2AL</rsm:PostcodeCode></rsm:Address>rsm:TelephoneCommunicationrsm:CompleteNumberTextChange Me</rsm:CompleteNumberText></rsm:TelephoneCommunication>rsm:FaxCommunicationrsm:CompleteNumberTextChange Me</rsm:CompleteNumberText></rsm:FaxCommunication>rsm:EmailCommunicationrsm:EmailURIIDprtr@defra.gsi.gov.uk</rsm:EmailURIID></rsm:EmailCommunication>rsm:ContactPersonNameNational Data Manager</rsm:ContactPersonName>

Comment: Can you post a relevant small sample of XML in body of post? Links can change for future readers and we don't have to download potentially large files from external sites to help you. And please post root of XML in case namespaces are defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd approach this bit differently; this issue resolves on its own when we move from building column vectors to trimmed-down *FacilityReport* records (i.e. rows for future data.frame / tibble), if something is missing, we'll just have `NA` values in those specific rows instead of varying length column vectors.

We can start by finding all `rsm:FacilityReport` nodes; to speed things up a bit, we'll remove all subnodes that are not needed. From there, we can turn `reports` node-set to a list and create a nested tibble, hoist nested values.

```r
library(xml2)
library(dplyr) 
library(tidyr)

tictoc::tic("load and process")
xml_file <- read_xml('uk_prtr_dataset_2021.xml') 

# collect all reports
reports <- xml_find_all(xml_file, "//rsm:FacilityReport")

# collect and remove all other nodes so we could get a clean result from as_list(reports)
to_remove <- xml_find_all(reports, "./*[not(self::rsm:ParentCompanyName or self::rsm:FacilityName or self::rsm:GeographicalCoordinate or self::rsm:MainEconomicActivityName)]")
xml_remove(to_remove)

reports_tbl <- 
  reports |> 
  as_list() |> 
  tibble(report = _) |>
  # extract nested values
  hoist(report, 
        parent = list("ParentCompanyName", 1),
        facility = list("FacilityName", 1),
        main_act = list("MainEconomicActivityName", 1),
        lon = list("GeographicalCoordinate","LongitudeMeasure", 1),
        lat = list("GeographicalCoordinate","LatitudeMeasure", 1),
        ) |>
  select(-report)
tictoc::toc()
#> load and process: 7.28 sec elapsed
```

Resulting frame along with the record that caused issues:

```
reports_tbl
#> # A tibble: 6,306 × 5
#>    parent                 facility                          main_act lon   lat  
#>    <chr>                  <chr>                             <chr>    <chr> <chr>
#>  1 IQE (Europe) Ltd       IQE (Europe) Limited, St Mellons… Manufac… -3.0… 51.5…
#>  2 G B Davies & Co        G B Davies & Co, Plas Bach Farm   Raising… -3.1… 52.7…
#>  3 Hook 2 Sisters Limited Hook 2 Sisters Limited, Merllyn … Raising… -3.2… 53.2…
#>  4 Hook 2 Sisters Limited Hook 2 Sisters Limited, Morlais   Raising… -4.3… 53.1…
#>  5 Mills Poultry Ltd.     Mills Poultry Ltd., Pentreucha F… Raising… -3.4… 52.6…
#>  6 Mills Poultry Ltd.     Mills Poultry Ltd., Minffordd Fa… Raising… -3.4… 52.6…
#>  7 Mr Philip Weale        P J Weale, Highfield Poultry Farm Raising… -4.0… 51.5…
#>  8 Uniper UK Limited      Connah'S Quay Power Station       Product… -3.0… 53.2…
#>  9 Glas Cymru Cyfyngedig  Nash Stw - Final Effluent         Sewerage -2.9… 51.5…
#> 10 Glas Cymru Cyfyngedig  Five Fords Stw                    Sewerage -2.9… 53.0…
#> # ℹ 6,296 more rows

# offending FacilityReport:
reports_tbl[!complete.cases(reports_tbl),]
#> # A tibble: 1 × 5
#>   parent facility                       main_act lon   lat  
#>   <chr>  <chr>                          <chr>    <chr> <chr>
#> 1 <NA>   Newly created but not approved <NA>     <NA>  <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

A `rsm:FacilityReport` node for reference:

```
    <rsm:FacilityReport>
        <rsm:NationalID>Wales_KP3235SS</rsm:NationalID>
        <rsm:PreviousNationalID>
            <rsm:NationalID>Wales_KP3235SS</rsm:NationalID>
            <rsm:ReportingYear>2020</rsm:ReportingYear>
        </rsm:PreviousNationalID>
        <rsm:ParentCompanyName>IQE (Europe) Ltd</rsm:ParentCompanyName>
        <rsm:FacilityName>IQE (Europe) Limited, St Mellons Semiconductor Plant</rsm:FacilityName>
        <rsm:Address>
            <rsm:StreetName>Cypress Drive, Cardiff</rsm:StreetName>
            <rsm:BuildingNumber>--</rsm:BuildingNumber>
            <rsm:CityName>Cardiff</rsm:CityName>
            <rsm:PostcodeCode>CF3 0LW</rsm:PostcodeCode>
        </rsm:Address>
        <rsm:GeographicalCoordinate>
            <rsm:LongitudeMeasure>-3.085770</rsm:LongitudeMeasure>
            <rsm:LatitudeMeasure>51.530800</rsm:LatitudeMeasure>
        </rsm:GeographicalCoordinate>
        <rsm:RiverBasinDistrictID>UK09</rsm:RiverBasinDistrictID>
        <rsm:NACEMainEconomicActivityCode>27.90</rsm:NACEMainEconomicActivityCode>
        <rsm:MainEconomicActivityName>Manufacture of other electrical equipment</rsm:MainEconomicActivityName>
        <rsm:CompetentAuthorityPartyName>NRW02</rsm:CompetentAuthorityPartyName>
        <rsm:NutsRegionID>UKL2</rsm:NutsRegionID>
        <rsm:ConfidentialIndicator>0</rsm:ConfidentialIndicator>
        <rsm:ProtectVoluntaryData>0</rsm:ProtectVoluntaryData>
        <rsm:Activity>
            <rsm:RankingNumeric>1</rsm:RankingNumeric>
            <rsm:AnnexIActivityCode>4.(b).(v)</rsm:AnnexIActivityCode>
        </rsm:Activity>
        <rsm:PollutantRelease>
            <rsm:MediumCode>AIR</rsm:MediumCode>
            <rsm:PollutantCode>NH3</rsm:PollutantCode>
            <rsm:MethodBasisCode>C</rsm:MethodBasisCode>
            <rsm:MethodUsed>
                <rsm:MethodTypeCode>OTH</rsm:MethodTypeCode>
                <rsm:Designation>none specified</rsm:Designation>
            </rsm:MethodUsed>
            <rsm:TotalQuantity unitCode="KGM">1.98</rsm:TotalQuantity>
            <rsm:AccidentalQuantity unitCode="KGM">0.00</rsm:AccidentalQuantity>
            <rsm:ConfidentialIndicator>0</rsm:ConfidentialIndicator>
            <rsm:RemarkText>significant drop 2020 v 2021 is due to vastly decreased ammonia emissions to air.</rsm:RemarkText>
        </rsm:PollutantRelease>
        <rsm:PollutantRelease>
            <rsm:MediumCode>AIR</rsm:MediumCode>
            <rsm:PollutantCode>AS AND COMPOUNDS</rsm:PollutantCode>
            <rsm:MethodBasisCode>C</rsm:MethodBasisCode>
            <rsm:MethodUsed>
                <rsm:MethodTypeCode>OTH</rsm:MethodTypeCode>
                <rsm:Designation>none specified</rsm:Designation>
            </rsm:MethodUsed>
            <rsm:TotalQuantity unitCode="KGM">6.56</rsm:TotalQuantity>
            <rsm:AccidentalQuantity unitCode="KGM">0.00</rsm:AccidentalQuantity>
            <rsm:ConfidentialIndicator>0</rsm:ConfidentialIndicator>
        </rsm:PollutantRelease>
        <rsm:WasteTransfer>
            <rsm:WasteTypeCode>NON-HW</rsm:WasteTypeCode>
            <rsm:WasteTreatmentCode>D</rsm:WasteTreatmentCode>
            <rsm:Quantity unitCode="TNE">2.60</rsm:Quantity>
            <rsm:MethodBasisCode>C</rsm:MethodBasisCode>
            <rsm:MethodUsed>
                <rsm:MethodTypeCode>OTH</rsm:MethodTypeCode>
                <rsm:Designation>none specified</rsm:Designation>
            </rsm:MethodUsed>
            <rsm:ConfidentialIndicator>0</rsm:ConfidentialIndicator>
            <rsm:RemarkText>2021 non-hazardous waste to landfill.</rsm:RemarkText>
        </rsm:WasteTransfer>
        <rsm:WasteTransfer>
            <rsm:WasteTypeCode>NON-HW</rsm:WasteTypeCode>
            <rsm:WasteTreatmentCode>R</rsm:WasteTreatmentCode>
            <rsm:Quantity unitCode="TNE">7.56</rsm:Quantity>
            <rsm:MethodBasisCode>C</rsm:MethodBasisCode>
            <rsm:MethodUsed>
                <rsm:MethodTypeCode>OTH</rsm:MethodTypeCode>
                <rsm:Designation>none specified</rsm:Designation>
            </rsm:MethodUsed>
            <rsm:ConfidentialIndicator>0</rsm:ConfidentialIndicator>
            <rsm:RemarkText>waste to energy - 5107kg&#13;
recycling - 2576kg</rsm:RemarkText>
        </rsm:WasteTransfer>
        <rsm:WasteTransfer>
            <rsm:WasteTypeCode>HWIC</rsm:WasteTypeCode>
            <rsm:WasteTreatmentCode>D</rsm:WasteTreatmentCode>
            <rsm:Quantity unitCode="TNE">236</rsm:Quantity>
            <rsm:MethodBasisCode>C</rsm:MethodBasisCode>
            <rsm:MethodUsed>
                <rsm:MethodTypeCode>OTH</rsm:MethodTypeCode>
                <rsm:Designation>none specified</rsm:Designation>
            </rsm:MethodUsed>
            <rsm:ConfidentialIndicator>0</rsm:ConfidentialIndicator>
        </rsm:WasteTransfer>
    </rsm:FacilityReport>
```